# jQuery datatable functionality inoperable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I've been working with Datatables for a while, but apparently, I haven't been using them the right way.

In the past, I would start my datatable using $.post, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('process/recordTables.php', function(data)
  {
    var table = $('#example1').DataTables();
    table.clear();
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    obj.forEach(function(item)
    {
      table.row.add([item.column1, item.column2, //and so on]);
    });
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

The above code works.  My datatable prints the data I need.  Within the obj.forEach, I can set columns with href tags and other features, if necessary.

But, if I want to be able to reload the Datatable on set intervals, I cannot use the above method.  It has to be using the "ajax" method.

After a few trial and errors, using the code below, I was able to print out the "correct" form (and use) of the jQuery Datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('#example1').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true, 
    "ajax": {
      "url": "process/recordTables.php", // same url as the above code
      "type": "POST",
      "dataSrc": ''
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "" },
      { "data": "column1" },
      { "data": "column2" },
      { "data": "column3" },
      // and so on
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    "scrollY": 550,
    "scrollX": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "stateSave": true,  
     // few others that don't seem to affect functionality
  });
});
```

Using the code immediately above, I was able to display the same data using the $.post method.

However...none of the functionality works.  The sorting doesn't work.  The pagination, the search filter, the data info at the bottom of the table displays "0 out of 0 entries".  Nothing works.

What am I missing that will fix this problem?  I am perplexed.

### Edit

Here is the HTML table:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    // and so on
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML related to this DataTable? And having the attribute dataSrc with value ' ' will display no data. Remove that attribute completly.

Comment: Added the table.  I did have TR and TD tags withing the TBODY, but still got the same results.

Comment: Your HTML is fine, shouldn't need to touch it as long as the th count matches the columns in the dataTable definition.

Comment: Yes indeed.  The column count does match.

Comment: Try removing the the empty dataSrc. I tested on a working datatable and it removes all the data when the attribute is empty. Other than that, your dataTable code looks fine.

Comment: Removed the empty dataSrc, but the datatable came out blank.

Comment: A somewhat trivial question: any errors showing on the dev console?

Comment: @kobyDouek - No console errors.  In a way, I wish there was.

Comment: Voted up, this is a good question. I'm baffled.

Comment: It is becuase you have `"serverSide": true` ...If that is set all sorting, filtering and so on is expected to be executed serverside.

Comment: @davidkonrad Ah. How did I miss that?

Comment: @davidkonrad - Wow....just wow.  Everything appears to be fixed now.  Thank you, sir.  Thanks to everyone who helped.  Upvotes for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `"serverSide": true`, attribute, your setting your `DataTable` as [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). In which case, all client-side processing is disabled:

> With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server

Comment: @davidkonrad I made a mistake and copied the wrong attribute... snap. corrected now.